# How to reset android studio font

Tags: android, fonts, android-studio

I tryed changing the font in the appearance settings and now everything is huge.
Is there a way to reset only the font ? 
I tried to change it to other font but i just cant see anyting, Thank you.
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRyyE.jpg !http://imgur.com/wN4Klou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double tap `Shift` or use `Ctrl+Alt+A` to bring up the search everywhere dialog in Android Studio. Then type in "decrease font size" and just click on the only option. The same works for searching "increase font size" to make it larger.

[image: Screen shot of search]

Comment: The problem is that i can't see anyting its like everything is out of position

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you add a screen shot to your question?

Comment: Is there a way to send you the screen shot because i dont have 10 points to post pictures

Comment: Sorry, I asked a few other people and even they had no idea what was going on. The only other thing to try if you don't get an answer is to uninstall AS and reinstall it

Comment: I fixed it, it happened when i disabled override default fonts in appearance. Thank you for your help :)