# How To Restore Android Studio Font

Tags: android-studio

I was trying to change the font of Android Studio. I selected a font and pressed Apply Changes button of the Dialog and from then onward my android studio looks like this.

[image: android studio]

I re-install the software which also doesn't solve the problem.

I also tried to change the theme font from the xml file located at `C:\Users\tuser\.AndroidStudio1.5\config\colors\Obsidian\` which is also not working.

I Read, [How to reset android studio font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668029/how-to-reset-android-studio-font),  and tried pressing `shift` twice and `ctrl + shift + a`, the search dialog appears like this

[image]

So, How can i restore the font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help (I see you're using windows):

> Go to your User Folder - on Windows 7/8 this would be:
>
> [SYSDRIVE]:\Users[your username] (ex. C:\Users\JohnDoe)
>
> In this folder there should be a folder called  .AndroidStudio (notice
>   the period at the start - so on some OSes it would be hidden).
>
> Delete this folder (or better yet, move it to a backup location - so
>   you can return it if something goes wrong).
>
> This should reset your Android Studio settings to default.

The answer is from:

[How to reset Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384033/how-to-reset-android-studio) by `free3dom` author.